# C++11/14/17, GCC 7 vs GCC 8: Name lookup for friend class templates

Tags: c++, gcc, standards, c++17

I'm trying to figure out while the following code works in GCC 7, but not in GCC 8.1.

What the code does is:

- define (and forward declare) a class template `MyGoodFriend` (in global namespace)
- define a class template `Befriended` inside the `inner` namespace
- Make all specializations of `MyGoodFriend` a friend of `Befriended`

The problematic piece is

```
        template<class FA>
        friend class MyGoodFriend;
```

I get what the problem is. GCC 8.1 requires me to use the fully-qualified name `::MyGoodFriend` in the `friend` declaration - however, GCC 7 was happy with just `MyGoodFriend`. This is the code:

```
template<class A>
class MyGoodFriend;

namespace inner {
    template<class T>
    class Befriended {
    private:
        int i;
        T t;

        template<class FA>
        friend class MyGoodFriend;
        // This works for gcc 8.1:
        // template<class FA>
        //friend class ::MyGoodFriend;
    };
} // namespace inner

template<class A>
class MyGoodFriend {
public:
    void do_something() {
        inner::Befriended<bool> bf;
        bf.i = 42;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyGoodFriend<int> mgf;
    mgf.do_something();
}
```

You can test this with GCC 7 vs 8 here: https://godbolt.org/g/6u9rgy

Two questions:

### Why did the behavior of GCC change?

Was GCC 7 misinterpreting the standard? Or is this a mistake in GCC 8?

### If GCC 8 is correct: Why?

If I read the standard correctly (referring to the C++14 standard here):
Section 3.4 (which specifies how name lookup works), Point 7.4 states:

> A name used in the definition of a class X […]
>
> - if X is a member of namespace N, or is a nested class of a class that
>     is a member of N, or is a local class or a nested class within a local
>     class of a function that is a member of N, before the definition of
>     class X in namespace N or in one of N ’s enclosing namespaces

Obviously, `MyGoodFriend` is declared in an enclosing namespace, so it should be visible in `Befriended` - right?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've seen something similar a few month ago.

Comment: I don't see any different in behavior between gcc 7 and 8 in your example?

Comment: @Barry oh yes, sorry! I simplified my example to the point that it also didn't compile anymore with GCC 7. The crucial point is that the `Befriended` class also needs to be a template. I changed my code above!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [[namespace.memdef]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3.sentence-4), emphasis mine (the wording is the same in C++11):

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template<sup>99</sup> the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. [...] If the name in a friend declaration is neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration is a function or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared **shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace**.

That is, when you write:

```
template<class FA>
friend class MyGoodFriend;
```

We only look for `inner::MyGoodFriend`, not `::MyGoodFriend`. Since we don't find it, we consider it to be a forward declaration of the class template `inner::MyGoodFriend`. As a result, `::MyGoodFriend` is not `friend`ed.

---

With the revision, gcc 7 compiled likely because of one of the many template-access related bugs. See this [meta-bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59002). gcc 8's behavior is correct.

Comment: So making it `template<class FA> friend class ::MyGoodFriend;` fixes the problem.  Nice!

Comment: Does not it look first for inner::Befriend::Goodfriend?

Comment: @Barry Good catch - I didn't see that. However, according to http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:simple-template-id , `MyGoodFriend` should be a `simple-template-id`, therefore a `template-id`, and the `… is neither qualified nor a template-id … ` shouldn't be fulfilled, right?